# The two-loop $\beta$-function of the $\phi^4$ model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

just recently I took an exam in QFT and the preamble was the following:

We consider the $\phi^4$-model in $d = 4- \epsilon$ dimensions, defined by the action

$$S = \int d^dx \left(\partial_{\mu}\phi(x) \partial^{\mu}\phi(x) +\frac{m^2}{2}\phi(x)^2+\frac{\lambda}{4!} \phi^4(x)  \right).$$

The point of the exam was to derive the 2-loop $\beta$-function of this model. Now the first question was:

Why are we interested in the $\beta$-function of this model at $2$-loops?

I am not even sure what this question means. Is there anything special happening to the $\beta$-function at 2 loops? Since now the exam is over, I would like to know what the answer would have been.

Comment: Just speculating, but I wonder if the idea was to use the second order term to figure out if the theory is asymptotically free. See, eg, slides 45-51 of https://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/fs09/pert/Asymptotic1.pdf. That's not really justified because there's no reason to trust just the first and second order terms while ignoring all the higher order terms, but it's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: Yeah I already thought about that, but in our lecture notes it already says that the $\phi$^4 model has a Landau pole at one loop order and that is why it can already not be a fundamental theory of nature. So, I reckoned that the question had already been answered. It would however be in alignment of a previous QFT exam that the professor posed. But I am not convinced

Comment: The only other answer I can think of for why you would be interested in the 2-loop beta function is because you want to get a good score on the exam :-)

Comment: That is technically what I wrote ^^

Comment: What is the point of adding a pure "I don't know" comment? Multi-loop calculations in $\phi^4$ theory have attracted interest since the 70s because they allow you to estimate critical exponents for all 3d materials in the Ising universality class. Additionally, someone who only cares about two-loop renormalization of gauge theories would do well to practice on a simpler theory first.

Comment: Oh and the answer in MS-bar scheme is $\beta(\lambda) = -\epsilon \lambda + 3\lambda^2 - \frac{17}{3} \lambda^3 + \dots$ according to "Critical properties of $\phi^4$ theories" by Kleinert.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, we had practiced on a simpler model first, we had calculated the beta function at 1 loop and at $\lambda^2$ and this result is what I got if you set $\lambda=\frac{1}{(4 \pi) ^{(d/2)} \Gamma(d/2)}g. $ with $g$ the dimension less coupling.  The problem was not the difficulty of the calculation.